# Pydrive : How to read file from Shared Drive?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I successsed to have all my shared drive IDs but when I am trying to read these it returns me empty an list:

```
for myfile in file_list:
    if myfile['id'] == 'file_id' and myfile['title'] == 'file_tittle' :
        file_list =  drive.ListFile({'q':"'file_id' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
        for i in file_list:
            print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to set the parameters `supportsAllDrives` and `includeItemsFromAllDrives` to `true`

This is specified in the [Parameters section](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#parameters) for the method.

Sample:

```py
file_list = drive.ListFile({
    'q': "'file_id' in parents and trashed=false",
    'supportsAllDrives': True,  
    'includeItemsFromAllDrives': True
}).GetList()
```

Comment: And for sort by img/jpeg like in GDrive, you have an option that display all img in a folder (even if there are some in sub-folder) Thanks

Comment: You can specify in the query `mimeType = 'image/jpeg'` but unfortunately it will not return you the results in the subfolders - for this you have to manually iterate through all subfolders.

Comment: Thanks you so much !